# Как создать страницу на основе данных из базы данных?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Допустим у меня есть база данных где находятся пользователи под названием user и папка user. Возможно ли сделать такое, чтобы при открытии сайта по ссылке mysite.ru/user/1. Где user это папка, а 1 - айди из бд без создания файла. Я пытался прочитать ссылку, но при вводе не созданной папки перевод на 404 ошибку. Пытался на странице 404 тоже внедрить код. также безуспешно. Подскажите куда копать. PHP

```
$url = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
```

Comment: если голый `PHP` то скорее всего нужно делать перенаправление (`RewriteRule`) с помощью `.htaccess`, берете строку запроса, выдергиваете из пути параметры и перенаправляете на свой `php` скрипт как аргументы `GET запроса`,  я с фреймворками не работал может там что-то есть.

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно реализовать такое поведение на PHP, используя функцию .htaccess для переадресации запросов.

Для начала, необходимо создать .htaccess файл в корневой директории вашего сайта (если он еще не существует). В этом файле можно настроить правила перенаправления запросов.

Вот пример правила .htaccess, которое перенаправляет запросы вида mysite.ru/user/1 на файл index.php, и передает в него параметры запроса:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: То есть, я переменную $1 буду просто отправлять на индексовый файл и неважно чему равна переменная, а ссылка будет сохранться /user/1?

Comment: Все я понял просто user/

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user/index.php?id=$1

и будет открываться ссылка как я писал при переходе на user/1 ссылка будет та же